# What happened to NUnit?

Tags: tdd, nunit

Why isn't this project maintained anymore?  I love this app, however not updating it seems like a crime against all .Net developers. There are several items that I would love to add to it given the chance of a future release.

Can anyone share something I don't know?

Comment: hrmm.  last time I checked it hadn't had a release for quite some time.  Glad it's updated now!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The NUnit 2.5 Alpha 4 Release was released on September 14, 2008.

Do you consider 16 days as not being maintained?

Comment: Heh.  16 days is soooo long.  Guess it was stagnant for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

http://nunit.org shows that the latest release is 2.4.8, released on July 21, 2008. It looks like it's still an active project to me.

Answer (score -2):

You are right. NUnit is a great app (or rather a system).

But since it is a open project, everyone is responsible for maintaining it. The people who originally started the great work might have some personal constraints stopping them actively taking part in development...